# Inserting row_number into a table (teradata)

Tags: insert, teradata, row-number

I am trying to add a identity column to a table I've made. The solution I've been using was to insert a row number

```
INSERT INTO MKTcampaign_ism.temptable
SEL 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY clubcode, campaigncode, region)
FROM MKTcampaign_ism.GO_Upgrade_Campaign_Ref
```

Query Failed:
`3706 syntax error expected something between the beginning of the request and the word insert into MKTcampaign_ism`

Comment: The text you pasted has "no-break space" characters where there should be normal spaces. But do you really want a table that only has one column with row numbers in it?

Comment: the temptable has data in it. I'm not sure what "no-break space" is, can you explain it

Comment: A "no-break space" is a special character (Unicode U+00A0) that displays just like a normal space, but tells programs that re-flow lines of text not to place a line break at that point. The database parser does not recognize this as a delimiter so it is treating `INSERT INTO Mktcampaign_ism` (for example) as a single token. Retype the line with actual spaces (U+0020).